# Flutter Push Notification Not Showing

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make push notif with firebase in flutter, i get the token and send test on device, but the notification is not show.
[Messaging Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Ubo.png)

This is my code.

<main.dart>

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'api/firebase_api.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
  runApp(TesMagenta());
}
```

<firebase_api.dart>

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class FirebaseApi{
  //Instance for firebase messaging
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  //Function initialize Notification
  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    //Request permittion from user
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

    //Fetch fcm token for device
    final fCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();

    //Print token
    print('Token: $fCMToken');

  }

//Handle received messages

//Function initialize foreground n background settings

}
```

my console

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 5352): broadcast received for message
W/FirebaseMessaging( 5352): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
W/FirebaseMessaging( 5352): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete code to setup firebase push notification

use this code in main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  // If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
  // navigate to a chat screen
  if (initialMessage != null) {
    _handleMessage(initialMessage);
  }
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport(
      global: true,
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: primaryColor,
        ),
        home: const YourFirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data.toString()}");
}

void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
  print("notification clicked");
  
}

// check notificaiton permission
void checkNotificationPermission() async {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: true,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: true,
    provisional: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
}
```

and make sure you have followed all steps to setup firebase and firebase messaging.

Comment: Thanks for the code. In my case, i fix config file in my firebase, especially in build.gradle.